# Do Racial Spells count for Spellcasting Feat Requirements?

Tags: spells, feats

For example, a Tiefling's Infernal Legacy gives them the spells Thaumaturgy and Hellish Rebuke - they can cast those spells.

For feats like Spell Sniper with the requirement "The ability to cast a spell" would these Racial Feats apply?

Comment: Chances are you are asking about D&D 5e, but you should state that. The easiest way is by adding the appropriate tag (eg. [dnd-5e]) for the system you are asking about.

Comment: Also, Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!